# Azure search fetch multiple records

Tags: azure, lucene, azure-cognitive-search

I want to fetch multiple records from Azure index using one of the fields, but I am unsure that how many number of filters can I use in a single query. Suppose if I want to fetch 1000 records, can I add 1000 filters to the search query?

for example : I have a field called field_document_id and I want to fetch multiple documents given that I have the ids of the document. For this I am querying like : *&$filter=field_document_id eq '1', this will fetch me the document with field_document_id value 1, suppose I want to fetch multiple documents in a single request like this, I there any other way ? If I use multiple filters is there any limit to it?

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide more details? I believe you should be able to use one of the filter functions.

Comment: Added an example, hope it clears the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are limits in the number of filter clauses you can define however I am not able to find the exact number. This is what is mentioned [`here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-odata-filter#filter-size-limitations):

> There are limits to the size and complexity of filter expressions that
> you can send to Azure Cognitive Search. The limits are based roughly
> on the number of clauses in your filter expression. A good guideline
> is that if you have hundreds of clauses, you are at risk of exceeding
> the limit. We recommend designing your application in such a way that
> it doesn't generate filters of unbounded size.

Microsoft recommends that you use [`search.in`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-query-odata-search-in-function) function when you have a large number of filter clauses on a single field. According to the documentation, it not only overcomes the filter size limitation but is also better in terms of performance.